# Automatic functions in object 's object?

Tags: php, php-5.3

Consider this class:

```
class Test {  
    public $obj;  

function __construct ($obj) {  
    $this->obj = $obj;  
}
```

$obj has its own public functions. I call it through my code as `$t = new Test($obj); $t->obj->do();`

I want to allow $obj to be empty, without triggering errors. Is it possible to perform some trick with PHP 's magic functions to always return false if the function is not explicitly set? Also, would there be a solution for PHP < 5.3?

Comment: What class is this object of, or what interface can it implement? Type hinting could be useful here.

Comment: In my case, it 's PEAR 's PHP_Debug class, but Adam 's solution is generic and working fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test this right now but this could work:

```
class default {
      public function __call($name, $arguments) {
             return false;
      }
}

class Test {
      public $obj;
      public function __construct($obj = NULL) {
           if($obj === NULL) $this->obj = new default;
           else $this->obj = $obj
      }
}
```

Comment: Might want to pick a different name, `default` is a PHP keyword.

Comment: this was just a example of course, using some name space like Test_default will be good idea, You can try adding __call() to Test class and creating it instance in $obj by default but this would be problematic with huge class and You will not be able to use __call() for other purposes